# What if a moving radioactive nucleus decays? (while moving)

Tags: kinematics, nuclear-physics, conservation-laws, inertial-frames, radioactivity

If a radioactive nucleus decays while moving (consider alpha decay), will the energy of the decay products (consider thorium and helium when uranium decays) alter? I mean, according to energy conservation law, the initial kinetic energy of the radioactive nucleus can't be destroyed, so it must have converted into the  kinetic energy of the decay products! Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Do you think there is a problem with this conclusion?

Comment: moving relative to what?

Comment: forget every other force, it's just moving in air with some kinetic energy.

Comment: so you're asking what happens when it moves relative to air molecules? Kinetic energy is not lorentz invariant

Comment: Can one of the 4 close-voters explain what they find unclear about this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both energy, linear and angular momentum are conserved. This means that the total inner energy + kinetic energy  of the nucleus and the total linear and angular momentum is transformed into the  kinetic (inner) energy, linear momentum and angular momentum of the  decay products. The radioactive nucleus is in a metastable state that contains substantial inner (potential) energy that is converted (disregarding angular momentum) into kinetic energy and linear momentum  of the alpha particle and the kinetic energy and momentum (including recoil effects) of the remaining nucleus.